# Can WIX Tool set used to install IE Add on and Google Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, wix, ieaddon

i am already using WIX toolset to install my desktop app(windows forms). my question is can i use WIX toolset to install IE Addon and Chrome Extension along with my app. i mean the installer will install my app and IE Addon and Chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer about IE addons (presumably yes), but an installer can instruct Chrome to install the extension on next launch [via registry](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions#registry). The user [will be propmted to allow it](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/12/no-more-silent-extension-installs.html).

Note that the extension **must** be hosted on Chrome Web Store (but may be published as "Unlisted"). You [cannot programmatically install it from any other source](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. but i want both the IE add on and the chrome extension to be installed along with my app. i mean the MSI will install my native app + IE Add on + Google chrome extension

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: my question is that possible with the WIX toolset. if yes, could give me sample code or configuration to do that?

Comment: You are asking whether it can do so. I can only answer for Chrome (answer is "yes") and I can't provide any WIX-specific sample, but the link to the docs I gave you should give you the idea of what needs to be done.

Comment: i will try and give you my feedback

Comment: For Chrome, it's literally as simple as writing a few keys to the registry. Chrome will check them on launch and do the rest.